# EJB not getting injected resulting in NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, ejb

I am new to Java EE and have been trying to resolve this issue for almost a week.
This is the code in my session bean where in I am getting a `NullPointerException`. Found out that the entity manager is not getting injected.

The code from the session bean:

```
package session;

import entity.User;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> {
    @PersistenceContext (unitName = "EXAMPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
    }

    public UserFacade() {
    super(User.class);
    }

    public String validateUser(String username, String password) {
    System.out.println("in facade");    
    boolean pwdMatch = false;

    System.out.println("in UserInfoFacade validate " + em);
    try {
        System.out.println("username " + username);
        System.out.println("password " + password);

        if(em == null) {
        System.out.println("em is null");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("em is not null");
        }

        List results = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserName").setParameter("userName", username).getResultList();

        if(results == null) {
        System.out.println("results is null");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("results is not null");
        }
        System.out.println("Entity manger is open " + em.isOpen());

        if (!results.isEmpty())
        {

            Iterator userList = results.iterator();
            while (userList.hasNext())
            {
            User user = (User) userList.next();
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.getPassword().equals(password))
                {
                pwdMatch = true;
                }
                else {
                pwdMatch = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return "NULL";
            }
            }
            if (pwdMatch) {
            return "MATCH";
            }
            else {
            return "NO_MATCH";
            }
        }
        else {
        return "NOT_FOUND";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Caught exception in UserFacade " + ex.toString());
    }
    return "NULL";
    }


}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EXAMPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
      <jta-data-source>EXAM</jta-data-source>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

code for managed bean : userBean

```
package managed;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import session.UserFacade;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class userBean {

    private String username, password;
    private String response="" ;
    private UserFacade userFacade;

    public userBean() {
        this.userFacade = new UserFacade();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String validate() {
        System.out.println("in validate going to user facade" + username + password);
        response = userFacade.validateUser(username,password);
        System.out.println("validUser value  " + response);
        if (response.equals("MATCH")){           
            return "welcome.xhtml";
         }
        else
            return "index.xhtml";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your persistence.xml look like?  Also, what container and version?

Comment: Sorry, am new to j2ee, but how do i know what container and version?

Comment: Which server are you running on?

Comment: glassfish 3.x and IDE is netbeans 7.2

Comment: does injection of other slsb work?

Comment: This is my first one. Trying to create a login page so have not created many slsb. Am trying to see how to inject from tutorials but looks like i have dne the sme way

Comment: Can you postthe code that calls the validateuser

Comment: Have added the managed bean code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `new UserFacade()` will only do what it always does in Java: call the no-arg constructor of the `UserFacade` class.

To get a reference to an EJB, you need to have it injected into your managed bean, or to retrieve a reference to the EJB using JNDI.

Comment: @JBNizet: If the constructor is called, is not an Object of the class created? Shouldn't in his code the userFacade reference point to an Object, namely Bean, after the constructor is called?

Comment: @arjacsoh: A reference to an EJB is not a direct reference to an instance of the bean class, but a reference to a proxy which wraps this instance. The proxy is what makes it an EJB: it handles the transaction, the security, the exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use DI to inject to ejb in the managedBean, do not create the instance in the constructor of mb:

```
@ManagedBean @SessionScoped 
public class userBean {
    @EJB
    UserFacade  userFacade;
}
```

Comment: ya did that and it workd. Thank you all so much. I was thinking the error is in session bean so never checked my managed bean properly.